# C buffers clarification

Tags: c, buffer

I have a question about buffers in C. Basically, I want to create array using buffers and malloc. I know this isn't practical, it's mainly for practice. So I have my code like this:

```
uint32_t* buf;
buf = malloc (100*sizeof(uint32_t));
uint32_t i;
```

What I want to know is what the difference between the following blocks are:

```
for (i = 0; i<100; i++){
  buf[i] = i;
}
```

vs

```
for (i = 0; i<100; i++){
  *buf = i;
  buf++;
}
```

From my understanding, a buffer is just a pointer to an area in memory and the buffer points to the lowest byte. It's also my understanding that `buf[i]` is just `*(buf + i)`, which, at least in my thoughts(probably wrong) is just the same as doing `buf+i` and then `*buf`, which is what I thought I did in the second block. However, in practice, when I do a `printf(buf[i])` for the first block and `printf(*buf)` for the second block, the first block gives me a correctfor (i = 0; i<100; i++){
      buf[i] = i;
    } outupt of i, whereas the second block says everything is zero. Can anyone tell me what assumption of mine is incorrect?

Edit: for my output methods, I essentially just had `printf` statements inside the for loops, so like this:

```
for (i = 0; i<100; i++){
  buf[i] = i;
  printf("Value: %d\r\n", buf[i]);
}
```

Similar for the second block, but with `*buf` instead of `buf[i]`.

Comment: You should only alter the value of the pointer `buf` if you have a copy, otherwise you won't be able to `free` its memory. Note: you have not shown enough code to say whether your output methods were correct.

Comment: the second code posted is a very bad idea.  Because it loses the pointer to the malloc'd memory by incrementing that pointer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is because of moving pointer:

```
buf++;
```

Moves the pointer to next position, and original pointer is lost
In both cases buffer is filled correctly, but in second case you move the pointer one position behind the end of buffer

---

To save the original pointer, do this:

```
uint32_t* temp = buf;
for (i = 0; i<100; i++){
  *temp = i;
  temp++;
}
```

Thanks **@MiltoxBeyond** for idea using the `temp` pointer

Comment: Or you can use `buf+i`

Comment: Great, thanks, I suspected my error was along those lines. So in your example, if I switched `buf` into the for loop, it wouldn't work right? Because even though I have something that points to the start, `temp` would still get updated alongside `buf` since it just points to w/e `buf` points to?

Comment: Yes, exactly, `buf` pointer shouldn't be modified, it should still points to first element, if it won't, nothing cant determine, where the buffer starts @JustinWang,

Answer (score 2):

I guess you forgot to reset the array pointer before doing your print. If your first method was like this

```
for (i = 0; i<100; i++){
    printf ("%u\n", buf[i]);        // <--- note: the value is unsigned
}
```

and your second method was like this

```
for (i = 0; i<100; i++){
    printf ("%u\n", *buf);
    buf++;
}
```

then in the first case you print the same array, but not in the second which is missing a reset of the buffer pointer. You could do this in one of two ways

```
buf -= 100;     // reset buffer pointer
```

but far better to use a copy of the buffer pointer

```
bptr = buf;
for (i = 0; i<100; i++){
    *bptr = i;                  // assign
    bptr++;
}

bptr = buf;
for (i = 0; i<100; i++){
    printf ("%u\n", *bptr);     // display
    bptr++;
}
```

and then finally you can release memory with

```
free(buf);
```